# Build XML file from other xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

A site I work on uses a large XML file to populate text on screen. A method is used that grabs a single node of the document and returns an attribute from it.

I have been asked to create an additional XML file based on this, so every time a node is requested from the original file, I will write this node (including its parent nodes) to the new file.

Eventually we will have a copy of the original, that contains only nodes that are still accessed.

I want to avoid duplicate nodes and duplicate parent structures, basically my question is does this sound feasible using c# and XPath?

Comment: _"feasible using c# and XPath"_ versus what? What have you tried? Can you show us some code or explain better what edge you're looking for in your choice of framework classes?

Comment: Hi - I've not tried anything, I'm trying to research a solution before writing the code. I've a little experience with xpath and wanted to confirm i was on the right path.

Comment: I'm trying to ask you what right path are you looking for? XPath is a query scheme for searching xml nodes. C# is a general purpose programming language, you could do anything with both. If you put up some sample data and try something out and come up with a clear problem the people here can help guide you through.